Python Pandas: update last dates values of parameters with simple dynamics grouped by id
Here's a dataframe, with some parameters for each id by some regular quarterly dates. It's originally shuffled randomly, but, at first, let say, it is sorted by fab_date and id.
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
dt_to_fun = pd.DataFrame({
    'fab_date': pd.to_datetime(["2022-01-01", "2022-07-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-07-01",
                                "2022-01-01", "2022-07-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-07-01",
                                "2022-01-01", "2022-07-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-07-01"]),
    'id': ['n_01', 'n_01', 'n_01', 'n_01', 'n_02', 'n_02', 'n_02', 'n_02', 'n_03', 'n_03', 'n_03', 'n_03'],
    'param_01': np.random.choice([10, 20, 30], size=12),
    'param_02': np.random.choice([10, 30, 50], size=12)
})

dt_to_fun
    fab_date    id  param_01    param_02
0   2022-01-01  n_01    20  30
1   2022-07-01  n_01    10  50
2   2023-01-01  n_01    10  10
3   2023-07-01  n_01    20  50
4   2022-01-01  n_02    20  30
5   2022-07-01  n_02    10  50
6   2023-01-01  n_02    10  10
7   2023-07-01  n_02    20  10
8   2022-01-01  n_03    10  50
9   2022-07-01  n_03    20  10
10  2023-01-01  n_03    10  30
11  2023-07-01  n_03    30  50

The goal is: for each id replace (last date) param value like this: param_01(last date) = param_01(last date) + param_01(-1 date) - param_01(-2 date)
For example, id n_03 last value of param_02 is 50, previous is 30, two times earlier is 10, so the result should be 50 + 30 - 10 = 70. The same for each id and all param* columns. Only parameters in rows with last date for each id should be updated.
Resulting table should be like this:
dt_to_fun
    fab_date    id  param_01    param_02
0   2022-01-01  n_01    20  30
1   2022-07-01  n_01    10  50
2   2023-01-01  n_01    10  10
3   2023-07-01  n_01    20  10
4   2022-01-01  n_02    20  30
5   2022-07-01  n_02    10  50
6   2023-01-01  n_02    10  10
7   2023-07-01  n_02    20  -30
8   2022-01-01  n_03    10  50
9   2022-07-01  n_03    20  10
10  2023-01-01  n_03    10  30
11  2023-07-01  n_03    20  70

I've tried applymap, shift etc, but can not figure out, how this all should work together. Would appreciate any help.

IIUC, use a custom groupby.transform with diff and shift:
cols = ['param_01', 'param_02']

dt_to_fun.loc[~dt_to_fun['id'].duplicated(keep='last'), cols] = (
    dt_to_fun.groupby('id')[cols]
    .transform(lambda x: x.diff().shift())
    .add(dt_to_fun[cols])
)

Or with multiple groupby.shift:
cols = ['param_01', 'param_02']

g = dt_to_fun.groupby('id')[cols]

dt_to_fun.loc[~dt_to_fun['id'].duplicated(keep='last'), cols] = (
    dt_to_fun[cols] + g.shift(1) - g.shift(2)
)

Output:
     fab_date    id  param_01  param_02
0  2022-01-01  n_01        20        30
1  2022-07-01  n_01        10        50
2  2023-01-01  n_01        10        10
3  2023-07-01  n_01        20        10
4  2022-01-01  n_02        20        30
5  2022-07-01  n_02        10        50
6  2023-01-01  n_02        10        10
7  2023-07-01  n_02        20       -30
8  2022-01-01  n_03        10        50
9  2022-07-01  n_03        20        10
10 2023-01-01  n_03        10        30
11 2023-07-01  n_03        20        70


Thank you, both working fine. Wonder, which one is faster. Will try to measure later.

I've measured operation time on 1200000 rows dt, first variant takes 31 seconds, second variant (with multiple group by shift) - only 0.12 second.

You can use groupby and transform to get the calculations, then update the original dataframe with loc on the last duplicates by 'id':
params = ["param_01", "param_02"]

s = dt_to_fun.groupby("id")[params].transform(lambda x: x + x.shift(1) - x.shift(2))
m = dt_to_fun.duplicated("id", keep="last")

dt_to_fun.loc[~m, params] = s

     fab_date    id  param_01  param_02
0  2022-01-01  n_01        20        30
1  2022-07-01  n_01        10        50
2  2023-01-01  n_01        10        10
3  2023-07-01  n_01        20        10
4  2022-01-01  n_02        20        30
5  2022-07-01  n_02        10        50
6  2023-01-01  n_02        10        10
7  2023-07-01  n_02        20       -30
8  2022-01-01  n_03        10        50
9  2022-07-01  n_03        20        10
10 2023-01-01  n_03        10        30
11 2023-07-01  n_03        20        70


Thank you very much, works great. Will learn more about .transform.

Measured performance time on 1200000 rows dt, it takes 70 second to run.

If you are sure to always have at least 3 values per group:
def proc(s):
    s.iloc[-1] += s.iloc[-2] - s.iloc[-3]
    return s


cols = [k for k in df.columns if k.startswith('param')]
newdf = df.assign(**dict(df.groupby('id')[cols].transform(proc).items()))

# or, for comparison
tmp = df.assign(**dict(df.groupby('id')[cols].transform(proc).rename(columns=lambda k: f'new_{k}').items()))
>>> tmp
     fab_date    id  param_01  param_02  new_param_01  new_param_02
0  2022-01-01  n_01        20        30            20            30
1  2022-07-01  n_01        10        50            10            50
2  2023-01-01  n_01        10        10            10            10
3  2023-07-01  n_01        20        50            20            10
4  2022-01-01  n_02        20        30            20            30
5  2022-07-01  n_02        10        50            10            50
6  2023-01-01  n_02        10        10            10            10
7  2023-07-01  n_02        20        10            20           -30
8  2022-01-01  n_03        10        50            10            50
9  2022-07-01  n_03        20        10            20            10
10 2023-01-01  n_03        10        30            10            30
11 2023-07-01  n_03        30        50            20            70

